# Axios Async and Await Loop trough Post Request with Value from Array with Objects in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I am trying to call an existing API Endpoint with a post request multiple times in nodejs. For that I am using a json file with multiple hundred entries, a loop and axios post request. The content of the file in itself changes but not the setup as it is based on a template.

I am now running into the issue that it has to be in a synchronous manner (thats why the await) as the used file has an inherent order which would have to be manually change in the application of the api endpoint. So an array of [Object 1, Object 2, Object 3] schould be created in that order even if it is not the fastest way possible.

So for my riskPostRequest function I am unable to set the title in data in a way that it will be pulled from the array of objects during my async importRisk function.

```js
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8')
const myReadStreamRisks = JSON.parse(jsonString)
console.log(myReadStreamRisks)

const riskPostRequest = risk => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        port: 443,
        url: baseURL +  '/Risks',
        data: {
            parentFolderId: 11633, 
            title: myReadStreamRisks.title
        }
    })
        .then ((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.title,';', response.data.id)
            })
        
                    
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        
    }, myReadStreamRisks) 
} 

// Import the TeamStoreRisks
const importRisks = async () => {
    console.log('Start')
    for (var i = 0; i < myReadStreamRisks.length; i++) {
        const risk = myReadStreamRisks[i]
        const riskPost = await riskPostRequest(risk);
    }
  }

importRisks()
```

Comment: So you need to pass the `risk.title` as `title` in the request body and populate an array with the result of each query?

Comment: Yes. The risk.title from an Object in the array